# Crear varios objetos en una clase

Tags: java, bucle-for, clase, metodología

tengo el siguiente problema:
En mi clase `Cuenta`:

```
public class Cuenta {
    private final String titular;
    private double cantidad;
    boolean moroso;

    public Cuenta(String titular, double cantidad) {
        this.titular = titular;
        this.cantidad = cantidad;
    }

    public double getCantidad() {
        return cantidad;
    }

    public void setCantidad(double cantidad) {
        this.cantidad = cantidad;
    }
    
    public void ingresar(double c) {
        if (c < 0) {
            
        } else {
            this.cantidad += c;
        }
    }
    
    public void retirar(double c) {
        this.cantidad -= c;
    }
    
    public boolean cuentaMorosa(){
        
        if (cantidad < 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ("Usuario: "+titular+"\nCantidad: "+cantidad+"\nMoroso: "+moroso);
    }
    
    
}
```

La clase funciona correctamente, para crear un objeto lo hago de la siguiente manera:

```
Cuenta cliente1 = new Cuenta("Luis Lopez", 250);
```

Pero ahora necesito crear 10 cuentas, con nombres (A,B,C,...) pero no se me ocurre forma de crear usuarios de manera "masiva" con un bucle.

Comment: Intenta con un arreglo.

Comment: En la función cuentaMorosa() debes poner el return fuera del condicional, si no lo haces, no devolverá si es verdadero o falso. Al inicio del método crea la variable boolean esMorosa e inicializala en FALSE, si se cumple o no la condición dale valor TRUE o FALSE dentro del condicional.

Comment: Eso ya lo he arreglado, gracias.  
`public boolean cuentaMorosa() {
        boolean esMoroso = false;
        if (cantidad > 0) {
            return esMoroso;
        }
        return false;
    }`

Comment: Sobre el metodo cuentaMorosa(): sería más adecuado usar un verbo para nombrar el método, por ejemplo 'esMoroso' (mejor todo en ingles). La variable boolean moroso no hace falta tenerla en ningún lado del codigo. Sobre el retrun, podrías hacer directamente public boolean esMoroso(){ return cantidad < 0;}

Comment: Tu pregunta no se entiende. ¿Has intentado algo? ¿Qué errores tienes? Si necesitas crear N instancias de la clase, ¿con qué datos deben crearse esas instancias? ¿de dónde se tomarán los datos? Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para completar la pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes realizarlo definiendo primeramente un `Array` o `Map` el cual
contenga los valores para inicializar las 10 cuentas, ejemplo:

Inicializa valores de las 10 cuentas y agrega estos valores a un `Map`:

```
 Map<String,Integer> valores = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
 valores.put("Luis Lopez", 250);
 valores.put("Mihai Marin", 150);
 valores.put("Elena sys", 50);
 valores.put("Jorge Wright", 250);
 ...
 ...
```

Itera valores en Map y crea instancias de la clase:

```
 Cuenta cliente = null;
 for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : valores.entrySet()) {
   System.out.println("inicializando: " + entry.getKey() + "/" + entry.getValue());
   cliente = new Cuenta(entry.getKey() , entry.getValue());
 }
```